# How to quote several parts of email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I am receiving long email messages and in the reply I need quote several different parts of the original email.

But how to do that? How to quote several parts of an email message in Gmail?

Answer (score 22):

You can format any text as a "quote" in your message.

Simply copy-and-paste the first part of the text you want to quote, then use the text formatting options and select the "Quote" tool.

[image: Gmail formatting options]

(You will probably need to open the formatting menu first. The button for that looks like an underlined "A".)

If you prefer keyboard shortcuts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> is for the "Quote" tool.

Repeat for each of the parts you want to quote.

Comment: This fails if the text already includes quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Practically speaking, you'll need to quote more than you want and edit it down.

Before you hit "Reply", select the start of the text you want to quote all the way to the bottom of the last bit of text you want to quote.

Click "Reply".

The text you selected will now be quoted for you in your reply. Remove the parts you don't want and proceed with the rest of your message.

Comment: It's impossible to understand to me, that Google didn't add more human-being feature for this purpose.

Comment: I do it all the time; it works fine. Is there another email client which you think does it better?

Answer (score 1):

My friend and I built a chrome extension that does this exactly:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reformat-gmail-inline-quo/akndolpagcjaolannkpophkacklomagp

You can just highlight the bit that you want to quote, and click the green "Q" button.

[image]